# Show that a Code has the length of 4 and the hamming distance 4

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, coding-theory

Let $A$ be a $3\times 4$ matrix with the columns $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \mathbb{F}_4^3$ and $C$ the set of solutions of $Ax=0$.
Show that $C$ is a code with the alphabet $\mathbb{F}_4$ with the length 4 and hamming distance 4.

It is clear that the length is 4. How do I show that the hamming distance is 4?

Comment: See whether this helps you: https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.05.082/2014_spring/uploads/Main/Solutions%20to%20homework%204

Comment: It depends on the matrix $A$ whether the claim is true. It is kind of difficult to say much more otherwise. You can use the methods you learned in linear algebra to find a vector space basis for $C$, and see how the land lies.

Comment: Or, it may be possible to check that no three of the vectors $v_i$ are linearly dependent. That will do nicely, do you see why?